# why case sensitive and case insensitive?

Tags: xml, html, programming-languages, case-sensitive

Why is a marked up language like `HTML` case insensitive and `xml` case sensitive ? What is the basic idea of making a language case sensitive or case insensitive? And why and on what basis it is done?

Comment: Historical reasons. XML derived from SGML being case-sensitive, and HTML was originally case-insensitive for simplicity.

Comment: You may want to check the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for the type of questions you can ask on SO.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp HTML was derived from SGML as application. XML I guess is independent of SGML. Please clarify.

Comment: @AnubhavSaini you've mixed them (XML and HTML). Check Wikipedia for history.

Comment: @AnubhavSaini EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp : Both of them looks like they have SGML as their base when wiki-ed

Comment: yes. literally, HTML is Application of SGML and XML is derived from SGML.

Answer (score 3):

Simply: Case insensitive is usually easier for humans to write, while case sensitive is slightly easier for a computer to parse. In addition, with languages written in unicode, figuring out what is "the same letter with a different case" becomes less trivial.

That's largely it. Even where many identifiers will be created, it is rarely good practice to create different identifiers that differ only in case.

Comment: I'd argue "slightly easier" is an overstatement. Just run it through `ToLowerCase` or whatever it's called in your language of choice (of course, then you lose the original casing for error messages, but that's just extra credit and can be restored with a 20 line wrapper class storing both original and normalized casing). Of course this assumes decent string processing in said language. Of course, this does not solve the unicode issue, at least not entirely.

Comment: @delnan You're making my case for me - there is more complexity in dealing with case-insensitive code, which language designers (and implementers) rarely find interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There are benefits in being case-sensitive, and benefits in being case-insensitive. Opinions as to which is best are therefore likely to vary, and since languages are designed by people with opinions, it follows that languages will vary.

Being case-insensitive becomes much more complex when you are supporting the whole of Unicode rather than merely ASCII: since HTML tag names are all ASCII, while XML tag names can use a much wider repertoire, than may explain the difference.